# Microsoft Dynamics Installation Location when NAV_DvdLocation set to folder path

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

Good Day All;

I am installing Dynamics NAV in Azure Cloud, I have made good progress, but am stuck, I have downloaded Dynamics NAV from MSDN, it is loaded in a folder with the following path: **"C:\Dynamics\en-001_microsoft_dynamics_nav_2016_x64_7053002"**    In the Example-1VM.ps1 PowerShell file I have the following command **$NAV_DvdLocation = 'C:\Dynamics\en-001_microsoft_dynamics_nav_2016_x64_7053002\"**     when I execute the script in PowerShell I get the following error "Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'NAV_DvdVhdName'."  As all the software that I need is stored on my local system and not on a DVD, how best to set this variable so it reads the necessary location on my system?

It is rather simple I'm sure, but for the life of me I am drawing a blank.
Thank You
Christopher

Answer (score 0):

$NAV_DvdLocation = 'C:\Dynamics\en-001_microsoft_dynamics_nav_2016_x64_7053002\"

I have solved my question on my own, when asked for the dvd device I needed to replace that statement with the one above, but when I originally executed the above command I did so as such:

$NAV_DvdLocation = 'C:\Dynamics\en-001_microsoft_dynamics_nav_2016_x64_7053002"

Without the "\" backslash on the end, once I added this then the path was correct and all appeared to work normally.  Really rather dumb on my part.  Maybe this will help others.

Cheers
Chris